# Why is my polynomial regression with gradient descent not overfitting?

Tags: linear-model, gradient-descent, overfitting, polynomial

I wanted to implement linear regression with gradient descent from scratch and demonstrate how you can overfit when using too many polynomials. Unfortunately my model does not really overfit the data. Can someone explain why?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# make example reproducable
np.random.seed(42)

# Create data set
X = np.linspace(-5, 5, n).reshape(-1, 1)
y = 2 * X**3 + 5 * X**2 + 10 * X + np.random.randn(n,1) * 30

plt.scatter(X, y, s=15)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Nonlinear Data')
plt.show()

# Define polynomial features function
def polynomial_features(X, degree):
    """Add polynomial features to X up to the specified degree."""
    X_poly = np.ones((len(X), 1))
    for d in range(1, degree+1):
        X_poly = np.hstack((X_poly, X**d))
    return X_poly

# Feature scaling
def feature_scaling(X):
    """Normalize input features by scaling."""
#     mean = np.min(X, axis=0)
#     std = np.std(X, axis=0)
    min_ = np.min(X, axis=0)
    max_ = np.max(X, axis=0)
    range_ = min_ - max_
    range_[range_ == 0] = 1e-8
    # Replace zero standard deviation with a small constant value
#     std[std == 0] = 1e-8
#     X_scaled = (X - mean) / std
    X_scaled = (X - min_) / range_
    return X_scaled

def gradient_descent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iterations):
    """Perform gradient descent to optimize theta parameters."""
    m = len(y)
    J_history = np.zeros((num_iterations, 1))
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Compute predicted values
        y_hat = np.dot(X, theta)
        
        # Compute derivative
        derivative = np.dot(X.T, (y_hat - y)) / m
        
        # Update theta using gradient descent
        theta = theta - alpha * derivative 
        
        # Compute MSE (cost function)
        J = (1 / (2 * m)) * np.sum(np.square(y_hat - y))
        J_history[i] = J

    return theta, J_history

degree = 50
X_poly_train = polynomial_features(X, degree)
X_poly_train_scaled = feature_scaling(X_poly_train)

alpha = 0.1  # The learning Rate
num_iterations = 5000  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent

theta = np.zeros((degree + 1, 1))
theta_fitted, J_history = gradient_descent(X_poly_train_scaled, y, theta, alpha, num_iterations)

plt.plot(np.arange(num_iterations), J_history)
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Cost (MSE)')
plt.title('Gradient Descent: Cost (MSE) vs. Iteration')
plt.show()

y_train_pred = np.dot(X_poly_train_scaled, theta_fitted)
m = len(y)
in_smpl_fit = np.round((1/m) * np.sum((y - y_train_pred)**2), 0)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.scatter(X, y_train_pred, color='red', label='Fitted Values', s=15)  # Specify label for legend
plt.scatter(X, y,s=15)
plt.title(f'in_smpl_fit = {in_smpl_fit}',fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Predictor',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Target',fontsize=16)
# Add legend
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Whereas I would expect something like this (this example is taken from a book):

[image]

Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: It seems to be overfitting to me, look at the tails

Comment: The data in your "expected" diagram has a big gap in the middle, but your code uses `linspace`, so there are no big gaps in your data. The gaps are the places where the polynomial interpolation swings wildly, buy you've systematically excluded some of the swings by only plotting the function at the training points.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a smaller number of data points or a higher degree of the polynomial?

Comment: Also, compare the coefficients that you get from gradient descent to a reference implementation such as sklearn's linear regression. If your GD results have a larger error than the reference implementation, then you know you haven't found the optimal fit to the training data!

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate any potential coding bugs, I've rewritten the script to use standard python libraries for machine learning.

I also changed the data generation process to have a gap in the middle, similar to the diagram in OP's question.

The data in OP's "expected" diagram has a big gap in the middle, but OP's code uses `linspace`, so there are no big gaps in OP's data.

Also, the gaps are the places where the polynomial interpolation swings wildly, buy OP has systematically excluded some of the swings by only plotting the function at the *training* points. So I generate random data and also plot the true function at regular intervals.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

np.random.seed(42)

n = 500
# Create data set
# X = np.linspace(-5, 5, n).reshape(-1, 1)

X_small = np.random.randn(5) + 4
X_large = np.random.randn(n - X_small.size) - 3
X = np.hstack((X_small, X_large))


def true_fn(x):
    return 2.0 * x**3.0 + 5.0 * x**2.0 + 10.0 * x


def noisy_fn(x):
    return true_fn(x) + 30.0 * np.random.randn(x.size)


y = noisy_fn(X).reshape((-1, 1))
X = X.reshape((-1, 1))
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
plt.scatter(X, y, s=15, alpha=0.8)
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Nonlinear Data")
plt.show()


degree = 13
X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree, include_bias=False)
X_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_poly_train = X_poly.fit_transform(X)
X_poly_train = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_poly_train)

lingreg = LinearRegression()
lingreg.fit(X=X_poly_train, y=y)
theta_fitted = lingreg.coef_
print(f"rank: {lingreg.rank_}")
print(f"singular: {lingreg.singular_}")

print(theta_fitted)


x_test = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000).reshape((-1,1))
x_test_poly =X_poly.transform(x_test)
x_test_poly = X_scaler.transform(x_test_poly)
y_test_pred = lingreg.predict(X=x_test_poly)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(
    x_test, y_test_pred, color="red", label="Fitted Values"
)  # Specify label for legend
plt.scatter(X, y, s=15)
plt.xlabel("Predictor", fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel("Target", fontsize=16)
# Add legend
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The data looks like this.

[image]
We can get the desired result with a degree 13 polynomial.

[image]

The nice thing about this plot is that it also shows that the polynomial is fine in the places where the data are most **dense**. But the interpolation behavior in sparse regions oscillates.

I was never able to get the GD to work -- it always diverged. However, I suspect that it does not produce an optimal solution.

You can take a moment to compare the coefficients that you get from gradient descent to a reference implementation, such as `sklearn`'s `LinearRegression`. If your GD results have a larger RSS than the reference implementation, then you know you haven't found the optimal fit to the training data!

Relatedly, stopping optimization before the optimizer has found the exact minimum is called [early-stopping](/questions/tagged/early-stopping), and can have a regularizing effect similar to penalizing the $L^2$ norm of the coefficient vector.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Obviously my code does not find the optimal solution. But I'm asking myself why.

Comment: As I write, early stopping is regularizing. Run it for more iterations until it finds an optimal solution. Some details: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/145329/22311 (and obviously make sure there are no bugs!)